# Why Python hex() function is not working on a 64 bit binary digit that starts with 1?

Tags: python, python-2.7, hex, bin

I have a 64-bit binary string and I want to convert it to hexadecimal.
Here's is my simple code.
The [2:].upper is to remove the "0x" characters from the output value.

```
bnum = "0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
hdnum = hex(int((bnum),2))[2:].upper()
print("Hex Number: ",hdnum)
Output:  ('Hex Number: ', '4000000000000000')
```

For this example, the output '4000000000000000' is correct.
However, when I simply changed the bnum value by setting the 1st bit to "1" and the rest to "0")

```
bnum = "1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
hdnum = hex(int((bnum),2))[2:].upper()
print("Hex Number: ",hdnum)
Output: ('Hex Number: ', '8000000000000000L')
```

The output '8000000000000000L' is now wrong because of the additional "L" character at the end.

May I please know what's wrong with my hex() function usage and how to fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't really be using Python 2.x as it is not supported anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the info but the script will be used on our testers that has Python 2.x installed. I don't have permission to update or install the latest one.